# can I use macros to switch projects type?

Tags: c++, macros

Depending on processor, I see macros that is defined for each project. So, in **console** it's `_CONSOLE` and on **Win32** it's `_WIN32`

when I open a source file (.cpp) with IDE I get by default console environment.

- it it possible to switch to win32 or mfc using macros eg:

  ```
  #ifdef _CONSOLE
  #undef _CONSOLE
  #define _WIN32
  #endif
  ```

so I want the compiler asks me about `WinMain()` not `main()`

Comment: I'm fairly sure you need to do this with mode switches on the compiler invocation, not inside the source file, but I'll let someone who actually knows MSVC expand on that.

Comment: These should not be defined or undefined by the user. You can only check them to see how compiler is building your code and make specific code. You should have a look at Abstract Factory Design Pattern to make better use of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You shouldn't be undefining or defining any macros that are reserved to the implementation (unless the documentation of your implementation allows it explicitly). You can recognize such reserved macros from single underscore and uppercase character at the beginning, or two consecutive underscores anywhere in the identifier.

The macros that you refer to are called "predefined macros". They can be used to check compiler or operating system features, but not to enable or disable them.

Comment: This is not true in general.  I don't know of any cases off the top of my head where the Win32 API expects you to define a macro in the reserved namespace, but there are several such cases in POSIX, e.g. `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`.

Comment: @zwol it's generally true regarding to the C++ standard. If your platform supports another standard such as POSIX, then that another standard may specify an exception that defining `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` is well formed. But such code is not portable beyond POSIX... that said, I find it unlikely that any non-POSIX platform would misbehave if `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` was defined by the user. I added clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a fairly used practice to use MACROS for different types of projects. I've seen popular projects where people use 'em.

For example,

```
#if defined(_WIN32)
#  include <axxx.h>
#elif !defined(__ANDROID__) && !defined(__native_client__) && (!defined(__APPLE__))
#  include <bxxxx.h>
#endif
```

And regarding the `main` call, you can implement it,

```
    #if defined(_WIN32)
        INT WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR lpCmdLine, INT nCmdShow)
    #elif defined(_CONSOLE)
        int main()
    #endif
      {
         UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hInstance); //Incase of Console..
         UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
         UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);
         UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(nCmdShow);
         return 0;
      }
```